# Date formatting from BigQuery to Data Studio

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, looker-studio

I'm trying to connect Google Analytics data from BigQuery for visualization in Data studio; I can't get the date formatted in a readable format in data studio.

I've tried using this reg expression:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(date, '..../*.')
```

but i still can't get it to work. The text format is `'20210921'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `parse_date('%Y%m%d', date)`

another option is `cast(date as DATE format('YYYYMMDD'))`